# Matlab, Symbolic functions,

Tags: arrays, matlab

1. How can I ask a user to input a function ( of say : t) and store it as a symbolic function?
2. And after that I want to store all the symbolic functions in an array:
   Let's say my first function is : `f1 ( and I have gotten information of f1 by user in step 1 as f1=t)`
   second one is : `f2  (and I have gotten information of f2 by user in step 1 as f2=t^2)`
   Now I want to make an array 
   `A= [ f1, f2]`

such that I when I call `A(2)` it gives me `f2` which in turn gives for e.g. 4 when I write f2(2)

I already know how to get input as an inline function and by using this program (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33025-convert-inline-to-symbolic/content/inline2sym.m) I am converting it to sym. But I want an easier way if it exists.

Comment: Don't use `inline` functions at all –they're inefficient and as the documentation states, deprecated. You don't need anything more than `sym` or `symfun` and basic Matlab arrays or cells to do what you describe.

Comment: An array of type `symfun` is not possible, you have to use a cell array.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes. That is why I mentioned the use of cell arrays in my comment. `symfun` objects are like function handles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, it seems to me that what you want/need is not a true symbolic function, but rather a function handle. If this is the case I'd go for something like the code below. A apologize for "ugly things" like `while 1`,... but it keeps the example short:

```
A = {};
while 1
    str = input('Enter a function of t (simply press return to exit):','s');
    if isempty(str), break; end
    A{end+1} = str2func(['@(t) ' str]);
end
```

When I run it i can input some functions of "t":

```
Enter a function of t (simply press return to exit):t
Enter a function of t (simply press return to exit):t.^2
Enter a function of t (simply press return to exit):sin(t)
Enter a function of t (simply press return to exit):
```

The cell array `A` contains:

```
A = 
    @(t)t    @(t)t.^2    @(t)sin(t)
```

And you can call functions in the following way:

```
>>A{3}(pi/2)

ans =

     1
```

I hope I understood your question correctly and that this helps.

Comment: You should use [`str2func`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html) instead of `eval`. [This blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/03/13/using-str2func-for-anonymous-function-handle-creation/) explains why (if avoiding `eval` isn't sufficient for you). I agree that many times users don't need Symbolic Math, but the OP did say "symbolic" in the title and question and mentioned converting to `sym`.

Comment: @horchler: corrected the `str2func`. About the symbolic part,my guess is that the word "symbolic" is more a language issue than an actual requirement. The example provided by the OP only involves: input, storage and evaluation of a function entered by the user (e.g. a string).

Comment: @RAMANISHSINGH if this helped you, do not forget to accept the answer as valid! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work